# cURL error 77: error setting certificate file: ./cacert.pem for https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token

Tags: laravel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xampp

i am creating laravel backend application using XAMPP as a local server. I installed firebase sdk, i am trying to get reference but i get

cURL error 77: error setting certificate file: ./cacert.pem (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token

In my php.ini I already uncommented

```
openssl.cafile and curl.cainfo
```

tried to download new .pem file

tried to rename .pem file to curl-ca-bundle.crt  or .pem.txt

Also tried to put the file in different directories